# Using same credentials for Connect-MgGraph and Connect-ExchangeOnline

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, microsoft-graph

I'm working on a (powershell) script which creates a Service Principal using MS Graph and then wants to grant that principal permissions in MS Exchange. Both the Graph and Exchange are in the same Azure tenant (domain).

I would like the script to ask the user for credentials only once to do this, but both the `Connect-MgGraph` and `Connect-ExchangeOnline` commands prompt for credentials.

Is there some way to have just a single prompt for credentials here?

Is it just a case of adding the right scope(s) to the `Connect-MgGraph` command? Perhaps this also involves replacing the ExchangeOnline commands with ones that use the Graph interface to do the work directly?

Version 3.1.0-Preview1 of the Exchange Online tools (I'm currently on 3.0.0) has a `-AccessToken` option for `Connect-ExchangeOnline` which might be what I need, though I still need to know what scopes are required, how to extract the access token from wherever `Connect-MgGraph` stashed it, and possibly [get around the inability to get a token for scopes in multiple domains (or perhaps that is outdated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486338/how-can-i-use-both-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-scopes-in-an-oauth-2-request) though this now appears fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To use app-only access, the certificate is loaded from Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ when or is specified. Make sure that the certificate you're using is present in the store before calling . For more info, see[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/app-only?view=graph-powershell-1.0&tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. The script is not trying for app-only access (although that is ultimately what the script is trying to set up for some other purpose).  This is a script to be run by a person, and currently when they run it they are challenged for credentials twice, once by Connect-MgGraph and once by connect-ExchangeOnline. I would like to (somehow) use the credentials or access token or something from the connect-MgGraph authorization in order to have connect-ExchangeOnline not issue a second challenge for credentials.

Comment: It maybe depends on the authentication format.